# What is the best way to perma-link to a chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, permalink

Do the chat rooms generated by the automatic "let us continue this discussion in chat" feature last indefinitely?

If not (or even if they do), what is the best "canonical" link to a chat? I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32653769/1858225) is incorrect, and that NeilG's reasoning is correct, but the "let us continue..." link is in a comment on a *different* answer (NeilG's), so I posted a link to that chat-room in a comment on Ivaylo Strandjev's answer. I do not, however, see any kind of "share" button in the chat room, so I just copied-and-pasted the URL from the URL bar of my browser.

Is this the right way to preserve a chat for posterity and provide a link to it? I notice that I could also have shared the link to the *transcript* rather than the chat room, or I could have created a "chat-segment" bookmark and linked to *that*. Which of these (if any) is preserved indefinitely, and which is the "preferred" way to link to a chat?

Comment: When you hover upon the message in the chat, you will get a small pop up box where there will be a link named *permalink*. Copy the link and paste it where ever you want.

Comment: @BhargavRao Cool! Though that highlights one particular message, and in this case I don't think there's one particular message I want to link to--though I suppose I could just link to the last one.

Comment: Ugh. I got carried away by the title :D

Comment: @BhargavRao Well, hey, for all you knew, that could have been the perfect solution! And in the future, it may well be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rooms and transcripts are visible to everyone forever*.  The room shows the last 100 messages and may be frozen for inactivity eventually (you'd still be able to visit it, just not chat).  The transcript shows the entire history of messages by day and time block, but you need to join the room to chat.

It depends on what you want.  If you want someone to join you in chat, share the link to the room. If you want someone to read a conversation from chat, share the link to the first message in the transcript.

Using the chat bookmark feature is somewhat strange, as the bookmark shows up for everyone on the room's info page.  I'd recommend just linking to the first message rather than making a bookmark unless you feel the conversation is notable for everyone.

<sub>* barring mod intervention</sub>

Comment: If the user has logged in to chat before, you can invite them to a room by locating their chat profile (which on SO chat has the same id as their SO user, not so on SE chat).

Comment: @pnuts no, I mean their chat user page. Mine is http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/400617/davidism.

Comment: Say after 2 comments I see it necessary to open a chat room, I mean sooner than the automatic suggestion to open a chatroom, I am suppose to go manually open a chatroom...then invite the author or OP with a comment? Or there's some more sleeker way?